# Вопрос о if(errno==ERANGE)

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, не совсем ясно что это.... 
`if(errno==ERANGE)`, `if(state & ios::badbit)`, `if(state & ios::failbit)`

```
if(errno==ERANGE) 
        {
            cout << "Error! Number out of range!\n";
            //return 0;
        }
        if(!(isdigit(str[0])||(str[0] == '-')||(str[0] == '+')))
        {
            cout << "Error! In file is no integer symbols!\n";
            //return 0;
        }
        for(i=1;i<strlen(str);i++) if(!isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            cout << "Error! In file is no integer symbols!\n";
            //return 0;
        }
        if(state & ios::failbit)
        {
            cout << "Formate error!\n";
            //return 0;
        }
        if(state & ios::badbit)
        {
            cout << "Fatal error!\n";
            //return 0;
        }
```

Кто может доступно разьяснить? Что сравнивается с чем?
(Используется с библиотекой `#include <errno.h>`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В данном случае необходимо очень хорошо понимать битовую операцию &.

Пусть дано число state - и состоит из N битов. Тогда это число может нести информацию об N ошибках, если i-ый бит в этом числе равен 1-произошла ошибка, 0 - нет.

 В данном случае, если **state&(константа)!=0**, то произошла соответствующая ошибка.

**ios::badbit** - константа, отвечающая за ошибку, как и функция [bad](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/ru/io/bad)

**ios::failbit** - как и функция [fail](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/ru/io/fail)

 В переменную **errno** записывается ошибка считывания переменной. Ошибка **ERANGE** - возникает, если мы считываем в переменную значение, которое не помещается в переменную.

 Здесь список ошибок чтения - [ссылка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h)